# tensorflow - nn =>accuracy print error

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm, deep-learning

i use nn using the tensorflow.

multiful input  => linear regression .

i'm not exactly tensorflow example..

just i wannna success this example becuase of just checking.

( input data is fruit & water & vegetable
  output value is  real number(concentration)

So, i think this example is similar.

if you have more good example, please give me .. thank you.

if this source print accuracy , this have a error.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.contrib import learn

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

boston = learn.datasets.load_dataset('boston')
x, y = boston.data, boston.target
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.6, random_state=42)

total_len = X_train.shape[0]

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 500
batch_size = 10
display_step = 1
dropout_rate = 0.9

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 32 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 200 # 2nd layer number of features
n_hidden_3 = 200
n_hidden_4 = 256
n_input = X_train.shape[1]
n_classes = 1

# tf Graph input기
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None,13])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None])

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3'])
    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(layer_3)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['h4']), biases['b4'])
    layer_4 = tf.nn.relu(layer_4)

    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer


# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
    'h4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4, n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.transpose(pred)-y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# # Initializing the variables
# init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(total_len/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch-1):
            batch_x = X_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            batch_y = Y_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                          y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch

        # sample prediction
        label_value = batch_y
        estimate = p
        err = label_value-estimate
        print ("num batch:", total_batch)

        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print ("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
            print ("[*]----------------------------")
            for i in range(3):
                print ("label value:", label_value[i], \
                    "estimated value:", estimate[i])
            print ("[*]============================")

    print ("Optimization Finished!")

    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print ("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: X_test, y: Y_test}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You compute accuracy outside of the session.
Move it under `with tf.Session() as sess:`.

Comment: what do you mean??
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print ("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: X_test, y: Y_test}))